# Combobox items from Right to Left

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have custom 'combobox' and I'm using Arabic language and I need it from Right to Left, In default 'combobox' I can change it from properties but in this custom 'Combobox' its not changed, so how can I modify the class to make it Right to Left?

This is what I'm using:

```
Class AdvancedComboBox
Inherits ComboBox
    Public Shadows Property DrawMode() As System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode
        Get
            Return m_DrawMode
        End Get
        Set
            m_DrawMode = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shadows m_DrawMode As System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode
    Public Property HighlightColor() As Color
        Get
            Return m_HighlightColor
        End Get
        Set
            m_HighlightColor = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_HighlightColor As Color

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.HighlightColor = Color.Orange
        AddHandler Me.DrawItem, New DrawItemEventHandler(AddressOf AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AdvancedComboBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        If e.Index < 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim combo As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
        If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(HighlightColor), e.Bounds)
        Else
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(combo.BackColor), e.Bounds)
        End If

        e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, New SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor), New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))

        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear why the the RightToLeft property isn't sticking for you in the properties box, but since you are custom drawing, you should use a right aligned property.  Also, best to use TextRenderer instead of DrawString to match the renderer used by other controls:

```vb
'e.Graphics.DrawString(combo.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font,
'                      New SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor), New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))

TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, combo.Items(e.Index).ToString, e.Font, e.Bounds,
                      combo.ForeColor, Color.Empty,
                      TextFormatFlags.Right Or TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft)
```

Comment: Thank you its perfect, but there is a little thing if you can help me with i'll be great full, the problem is in the default `combobox` its also organized (the text alignment) when the user type in Arabic and English its appear as the user type and saved in the database, now in the custom `combobox` if i have 3 words like : Arabic1 English Arabic2 in database its appear like this in the custom `combobox` : Arabic2 English Arabic1.
by the way I'm showing 2 values in one row:
`ComboBox2.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | ({1})", p_id, p_name))`

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha I apologize, but I'm struggling with what you are asking in your comment.  If you want three items, in would just be `String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", p_id, p_name, p_other)` but I suspect that's not the problem you are facing.

Comment: my problem is the text does not come properly structured, Example:
lets say the user add 3 words 2 words in Arabic and 1 in English to the database like that `[ word1(Arabic1) word2(English) word3(Arabic2)]`,
the 'combobox' shown it like this `[ word3(Arabic2) word2(English) word1(Arabic1)]`

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha I updated the post.  TextRenderer does have a RightToLeft flag, too.

Comment: my Man :)
thank you It's perfect now, I'm so great full :D

Answer (score 0):

If it will always be Right-to-Left then you can do it in the `AdvancedComboBox` constructor:

```
MyBase.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
```